# How to assign names to the the density curves?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Attached to the post you see a density plot. I am asked to compute the volume of bike rentals during weather levels, named weathersit (on the right). I am further to assign names, say Bad, Very_Bad, God_Awful and I_Wont_Even_Bother. Preferably the names should be near or in the blue circle, seen in the attached Image.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(viridis)

#plotting the bike density
ggplot(Bikes_Washington, aes(x=cnt, group=weathersit, fill = weathersit)) + 
geom_density(color = "darkblue", alpha=0.2)
```

[Our plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecBBn.png)

Answer (score 0):

In `day` data, there only three categories exists, so I recode 1, 2, and 3 as Bad, Very Bad, God Awful. Also, it's recommended to change categorical variable as factor using `factor` or `as.factor`.

```
Bikes_Washington <- read.csv("D:/Prac/day.csv")
Bikes_Washington <- Bikes_Washington %>%
  mutate(weathersit = as.factor(weathersit)) %>%
  mutate(weathersit = recode_factor(weathersit, "1" = "Bad", "2" = "Very_Bad", "3" = "God_Awful"))

sp <- split(Bikes_Washington$cnt, Bikes_Washington$weathersit)
a <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
  d <- density(sp[[i]])
  k <- which.max(d$y)
  data.frame(weathersit = names(sp)[i], xmax = d$x[k], ymax = d$y[k])
})
a <- do.call(rbind, a)
Bikes_Washington %>%
  mutate(weathersit = as.factor(weathersit)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=cnt, group=weathersit, fill = weathersit)) + 
  geom_density(color = "darkblue", alpha=0.2) +
  geom_text(data = a,
            aes(x = xmax, y = ymax,
                label = weathersit, vjust = -.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution has helped tremendously!

Comment: Maybe you should accept this answer then.